# Сквозная аутентификация на удаленном домене

Tags: аутентификация, авторизация

*(Название вопроса и сам вопрос скорее всего будут изменены, когда понимание предметной области будет более глубоким.)*

Дано:

- локальная сеть с несколькими десятками пользователей,
- рабочие станции включены в домен *domain.local*,
- IIS7,
- сервер и рабочие станции - Windows.

Есть желание развернуть на удаленном хосте [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) в качестве Knowledge Base для сотрудников. По идее, можно ее просто развернуть, однако **хочется организовать сквозную аутентификацию**: если сотрудник в локальной сети, то Wiki узнаёт его, если вне сети - отправляет некий запрос на ключевой (?) домен (*OAuth, OpenID*?) и опять же не требует от доверенных пользователей ввода логинов/паролей.

Менее проблематичным решением было бы разворачивание Wiki на своем сервере, однако, допустим, что такой возможности нет.

Каким образом вообще возможно (если, конечно, возможно) организовать сквозную кроссдоменную аутентификацию.

Найденное по теме:

1. [Удобная кросс-доменная авторизация и персонализация для DDoS-устойчивого сайта(Илья Кантор на ADD-2010)](http://vimeo.com/19260629) - *видео*
2. [Кроссдоменная авторизация (1)](http://shaparov.livejournal.com/4817.html)
3. [Кроссдоменная авторизация (2)](http://ru-php.livejournal.com/1256484.html)
4. [Вопрос на Хабре о NTLM-авторизации без ввода пароля в PHP](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/39791/)

Comment: кросс доменнку попросту недадут браузеры, если у кого-нибудь и сработает но бедет регулярное выпадание. либо пердавать пароли открытыми(сам видел, работает но слишком не безопасно). Советую копать в openID  либо вводить пароли, пусть и одинаковые, но будет 100% работать и безопасно.